# Icon specified in info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my binary to iTunes Connect using Applicaton Loader. When I select the file and hit send, it sends for about a second and then this error pops up,

> Icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Default -Landscape@2x~ipad.png

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Did any of the answers below help solve your problem? If so please mark as the answer to help others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

Another setting that can cause the issue:
You have to make sure the icon files are also found under build phases/bundle resources

Comment: This worked and also fixed another problem, the one where no icon is displayed when archived. Thanks!

Comment: I looked under build phases and found both icon.png (which didn't exist as a file anymore) and Icon.png. I deleted icon.png and it worked.

Comment: I found out I had to much files in build phases/bundle resources which also causes the issue. Thanks mate!

Comment: ahhh thank you thank you thank you. i concur with powerj1984: die in a fire, xcode

Answer (score 23):

Edit your projects .plist file "as source code" i.e. open it in any old text editor. Then manually edit the icon file names until they make sense.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! My plist actually had a blank <string></string> in the list of icons, which was throwing off the validator.

Comment: This worked well - what happened in my case was having dups and / or incorrect file names for the required images. This seems to have been caused by dragging and dropping the image files from Finder onto the Target/build settings area (where the App icons are). Got odd messages like "default.png" already exists, do you want to replace. Saying yes put the file into the plist, but the image didn't show in the icon image placeholder in the target settings... just the old 'default' black one... so now I had TWO images, but Xcode was confused :))

Comment: Argh this was frustrating to find out. How does Xcode mess this up? Editing it in the plist view has no affect. Xcode please die in a fire.

Comment: I had a line of <string></string> in my plist file. I removed this line because there were already lines with the actual icon listed.

Answer (score 17):

The `.plist` is case-sensitive when validated and archived for upload to the App Store.

If you have this in the `.plist`:

```
icon-72@2X.png
```

the file name can not be

```
icon-72@2x.png
```

owing to the the case change of the x character .

Comment: I had the same problem with an icon.png referring to an Icon.png

Answer (score 8):

I rename the file and corresponding change the name of icon file in the info.plist and this solution works for me.

Answer (score 6):

1. Clean your build
2. Make sure the file is actually on the file system
3. Make sure you can see the file in the project navigator.
4. Most likely step 3 will fail. If so, drag the icon from the finder onto the Project Navigator. When asked, uncheck the "copy ..blabla" option because since the file is already there where you are dragging it to, it would fail. Once the file shows up in the Project Navigator you should be golden.

Comment: In my case, at some point Xcode added app-icon-iphone.png and app-icon-iphone@2x.png to the Info plist. These files don't exist, possibly because I renamed them, or changed artwork. In any case, iOS seems to skip non-existent icon files in the icon filename list. So the icons I did set, which did exist, was being used, despite the first two entries referring to no-existent files. Once I removed the first two entries, it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Also check that you dont have 2 icons with the same name anywhere in your project folders.

Answer (score 4):

I am thinking that the answer to this question will vary in time because Apple constantly changes the application validation rules. These validation rules will surface only when you are submitting your app to the AppStore.

In this particular situation, the validation error happened to me while uploading the app on 08/03/2012.

The solution was fairly straight forward. I had to move to icon files which I had located in a folder nested within the project directory all to way up to the **TOP LEVEL** project directory - one that has the project file in it. Once I did that and readded the files back to the Resources in my project the validation error went away.

Of course you should check that this issue is not caused by misspelled filenames i.e. differences between your plist file and true names of icon files on your file system.

Answer (score 2):

Another little issue that caught me out was an empty string. I got the cryptic failure message ...

```
Icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper:
```

And found this lurking in my plist

```
<string></string>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was similar problem's. I have resolve to do this

1/ delete your application Icone in your Target

2/ rename your icone ex: applicationNameSmall.png

3/ add your icone in your application.

This, works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Error is coming up because the App Store is checking names of icon files based upon yourProject-info.plist. If they don't match, error message.

To resolve this issue: Go to yourProject-info.plist in xcode and check BOTH "icon-files" and "icon-files(IOS5)" arrays. You'll want to make sure that each string corresponds with the icon files you have in the file directory.

Change or delete mismatched string names (I had to delete a blank string). Rebuild. As other posters have noted, names are case-sensitive, so be mindful of that too.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Icon.png files needs to be open in some image editing tool (e.g Adob Photoshop) and save as a new image. This works fine. Check attached images some times image properties don't change by renaming image file manually.[image: See the attached image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just added the image files it complained about to the project in the viewer. Not sure if that was the *right* thing to do, but it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a silly mistake, in my info.plist the i had Icon.png, and the real file name was icon.png (no uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the images issues it suggests.
2. Clean your project.
3. Build and run to make sure nothing has broken.
4. Delete the previous archive
5. Make a new archive (Product -> Archive)

This worked for me. I had to rearchive my application cause the previous one was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I gone to Targets->Build Phases and deleted from there old (test) icons which I had pushed early. Good luck:)