# XCODE: Icon specified in info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper Default@2x.png

Tags: xcode, validation, icons, info.plist, distribute

Alright, I have had maybe 20 issues with validating my project, and before that it was a breeze making it, but I'm at the finish line. I can't seem to figure this one out, and this is the last step before I'm done. So PLEASE HELP,
 thanks.

apparently since i'm "too low a level" to post screenshots, I found this site to grab a picture and put it to a link so here: http://i46.tinypic.com/2q9w4zo.png

Comment: This looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165664/icon-specified-in-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top-level-app-wrapper