# Should your plist ever contain <string></string>?

Tags: ios, plist

I see 3 occurrences of `<string></string>` in my plist file. Is this an issue? I started looking into the plist because I'm getting this error:

> Icon specified in info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper

So I'm curious what is the point of `<string></string>` and can I remove all occurrences?

Comment: Looks like this might help. Good luck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165664/icon-specified-in-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top-level-app-wrapper

Answer (score 2):

A plist is just like JSON it can be either a dictionary or an array.

It has values in key value format.

If you have an employee with employeeId, name. In JSON it would be

```
{
    "EmployeeId": 1011,
    "Name": "Employee Name"
}
```

Same in plist would be

```
<dict>
    <key>EmployeeId</key>
    <integer>1011</integer>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Employee Name</string>
</dict>
```

You can see that there is `<string>Employee Name</string>`. This just means that the value of of key Name is Employee Name and it's type is string. In your case it is just an empty string