# App icon size for new iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I realize that iOS 7 is not out yet and should not be discussed but I could not find the answer to this question anywhere and iOS 7 comes out in a few days.

I submitted my app for iOS 7 and I got a warning saying I am missing the icon size 120 X 120 which apparently is the new standard size for icons in iOS 7. What I don't understand is what I should name this icon because my app supports both iOS 6 (Default app icon size is 114 X 114) and iOS 7.

Does anyone know how I should name this 120 X 120 icon for iOS 7 and my old iOS 6 icon that was 114 X 114?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought retina icons were 114px, not 116 as you say. Also, couldn't you find anything in Apple's developer forums?

Comment: @NicolasMiari my mistake I fixed the 114. and If I had, I would not be asking here :)

Comment: I see... just can't believe no one asked yet. There must be a million people with the same issue these days ;)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName application, even you can contributr in it.

Comment: I'm searching since hours to find specifications about the iOS 8 Action Extension icon sizes. :-/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you name the file as long as you hook it up correctly in Targets General Tab. You just click the Folder icon and select the file you want to use. The naming convention only really mattered because that was what was in the info.plist by default for a new project.

[image]

And the Targets General Tab realy just sets values in the app's info.plist

[image]

Note: I have a build setting ICON_SUFFIX = "Beta" so my beta release via TestFlight has a different bundle ID and Icon so it sits along side my app store version and doesn't over write it.

Comment: Thanks I just hooked it up. However, I still get the warning when I archive the project regarding the 120 X 120 icon. Its named 120.png but you claim naming has no effect if it is hooked up right. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Next check that image is part of the project and in the copy build phase so that it gets bundled with the app.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use one asset catalog to organise your icon images, it's quite easy.If there is one image asset catalog, you use that one, otherwise you can new one. then select **Use Asset Catalog** in the **App Icons** part of **General** tab, you need to prepare the following image size and just drag the images to the corresponding location.

The icon sizes for iPhone and iPad for iOS 5~7 screenshot is as below:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PqMH.png]

or download it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PqMH.png)

Comment: Seems obvious, but since I didn't get the sizing at first: The "2x" slot for 20pt needs a 40x40 pixel image, the "1x" needs a 20x20 etc. Compare [this answer to a similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170520/ios-how-to-set-app-icon-and-launch-images#32136202).

Answer (score 1):

Here is online tool, [Icons Master](http://imageresier-agrastas.rhcloud.com), which will create about AppIcon.appiconset folde, take care how icons should be big naming convection as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the solution here. Anyone with this problem refer to this following post!

[iOS 7 App Icons, Launch images And Naming Convention While Keeping iOS 6 Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons?rq=1)