# Swift: How to change the applications icon?

Tags: swift, icons

I am writing a Swift application under Xcode. I did set under Assets.xcassets > AppIcon an png file for 16pt, 32pt and 128pt (all for 1x). Now I can see this picture on the left side in message boxes, but the application itself (in Finder and in the dock) I still have the default icon. Also: What is the difference between 1x and 2x?

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170520/ios-how-to-set-app-icon-and-launch-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1X or 2X refers to the image resolution. In other words @2x images have to have twice the size of their @1x counterparts. You want to make sure to add images for all resolutions. Otherwise you might see a generic or stretched icon on retina devices as seems to be the case at this point. There may also be a lag in displaying an updated icon in the Finder which could have multiple other causes, but the first step is to add all icon images.