# Xcode Validation

Tags: xcode, validation

Can anyone help with this:  Xcode 8

> iTunes Store operation failed. Your binary is not optimized for iPhone
>   5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch
>   display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the
>   Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to
>   {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the
>   top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you
>   localize your launch images.

I am a total beginner at coding and not exactly young either, so I wouldt certainly appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Did you read the message? What did you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem seems to be that you are missing some required resources for your app to be compatible with iPhone 5. In this case, it is the launch image.

Launch images are images shown to users while your application launches. They exist to improve the user's experience, especially with longer loading apps, so the user doesn't think their phone crashed while the app was trying to launch.

[This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNHOZJFNY-g) hopefully can help you set-up your launch images for your app.

Alternatively, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170520/ios-how-to-set-app-icon-and-launch-images#answer-32136202) also covers launch images alongside iconf for your app.