# How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, appicon, application-icon

When I create an app with a `flutter create` command, the flutter logo is used as an application icon for both platforms.

If I want to change the app icon, shall I go to both platforms directories and replace images there?, by platforms directories I mean  `myapp/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset` for iOS and `myapp/android/app/src/main/res` for Android.

Or is it possible to define an image as a [Flutter Asset](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/) and the icons are generated somehow?.

Comment: you can update appicon with two way, i have mention both way check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401560/8265484)

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/change-flutter-app-launcher-icon-59c31bcd7554)'s a new solution to this problem using appicon.co to generate the different icons. The nice of this post is that includes web, macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

Flutter Launcher Icons has been designed to help quickly generate launcher icons for both Android and iOS: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

- Add the package to your `pubspec.yaml` file (within your Flutter project) to use it
- Within the `pubspec.yaml` file, specify the path of the icon you wish to use for the app and then choose whether you want to use the icon for the iOS app, Android app, or both.
- Run the package
- Voila! The default launcher icons have now been replaced with your custom icon

I'm hoping to add a video to the GitHub README to demonstrate the above.

A video showing how to run the tool can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjNAxwcP3Tc).

If anyone wants to suggest improvements/report bugs, please [add it as an issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons).

**Update:** As of Wednesday 24th January 2018, you should be able to create new icons without overriding the old existing launcher icons in your Flutter project.

**Update 2:** As of v0.4.0 (8th June 2018) you can specify one image for your Android icon and a separate image for your iOS icon.

**Update 3:** As of v0.5.2 (20th June 2018) you can now add adaptive launcher icons for the Android app of your Flutter project

Comment: Is there any requirement for the image?

Comment: Do you have a recommended image size for the `image_path` image?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to say with confidence which is the best @Suragch. In my tests I've always used 3 different sizes. You can find these within the test directory of the GitHub project page: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/tree/master/test

Comment: I only found a reference to one size, `710x599`. What was the reason for choosing that? I would have expected `512x512` or `1000x1000` or something square anyway.

Comment: @Suragch just did a quick search for an icon on Google so I could quickly test it. I included two other icon sizes so people could try out the package (1024x1024 and 128x128), you can find these here: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/tree/master/example/assets/images

Comment: @MarkO'Sullivan, I haven't looked deeply into how your package resizes the images, so correct me if I'm wrong, but I would think that 128x128 would not be a desirable size. Is there a use case for it (outside of testing)? Wouldn't it require upscaling for the some of the larger image requirements of Android and iOS? Anyway, 1024x1024 sounds reasonable and I'll go with that.

Comment: Yep I've always noticed better performance with 1024x1024 out of all the example assets

Comment: Can I suggest that the packages read.me should provide recommendations on images sizes.

Comment: @Brett Sutton, you are wrong. The read.me does not contain any size recommendations. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: I find `flutter pub add -d flutter_launcher_icons` easier for adding the package to the project.

Comment: Always try to add natively first specially for app icons and splash screens, below answer is the good fit

Answer (score 499):

## Setting the launcher icons like a native developer

I was having some trouble using and understanding the [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) package. This answer is how you would do it if you were creating an app for Android or iOS natively. It is pretty fast and easy once you have done it a few times.

## Android

Android launcher icons have both a foreground and a background layer.

[image]

*(image adapted from [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html))*

The easiest way to create launcher icons for Android is to use the Asset Studio that is available right in Android Studio. You don't even have to leave your Flutter project. (VS Code users, you might consider using Android Studio just for this step. It's really very convenient and it doesn't hurt to be familiar with another IDE.)

Right click on the `android` folder in the project outline. Go to **New > Image Asset**. (Try right clicking the `android/app` folder if you don't see **Image Asset** as an option. Also see the comments below for more suggestions.) Now you can select an image to create your launcher icon from.

> **Note:** I usually use a `1024x1024` pixel image but you should certainly
> use nothing smaller than `512x512`. If you are using Gimp or Inkscape, you
> should always have two layers, one for the foreground and one for the
> background. The foreground image should have transparent areas for the
> background layer to show through.

[image]

*(lion clipart from [here](https://openclipart.org/detail/215188/lion-coloured))*

This will replace the current launcher icons. You can find the generated icons in the `mipmap` folders:

[image]

If you would prefer to create the launcher icons manually, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196511/3681880) for help.

Finally, make sure that the launcher icon name in the AndroidManifest is the same as what you called it above (`ic_launcher` by default):

```
application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Run the app in the emulator to confirm that the launcher icon was created successfully.

## iOS

I always used to individually resize my iOS icons by hand, but if you have a Mac, there is a free app in the Mac App Store called [Icon Set Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?l=en&mt=12). You give it an image (of at least `1024x1024` pixels) and it will spit out all the sizes that you need (plus the `Contents.json` file). Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45122603/3681880) for the suggestion.

iOS icons should not have any transparency. See more guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/).

After you have created the icon set, start Xcode (assuming you have a Mac) and use it to open the `ios` folder in your Flutter project. Then go to **Runner > Assets.xcassets** and delete the AppIcon item.

[image]

After that right-click and choose **Import...**. Choose the icon set that you just created.

That's it. Confirm that the icon was created by running the app in the simulator.

#### If you don't have a Mac...

You can still create all of the images by hand. In your Flutter project go to `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset`.

[image]

The image sizes that you need are the multiplied sizes in the filename. For example, `Icon-App-29x29@3x.png` would be `29` times `3`, that is, `87` pixels square. You either need to keep the same icon names or edit the JSON file.

Comment: if you were struggling to understand it, I'm happy to reply to any questions you have. Open an issue and I'll get back to you about it: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: @MarkO'Sullivan, thank you. My guess is that the package is fine. It is just that the documentation was hard for me to follow. For example, what size to use for the initial image, are the background layers getting created for Android, etc. It would be really helpful to have a detailed tutorial to guide a beginner through the process.

Comment: This helped. Within Android Studio, there is no option to add *Image Asset*. The work around I learnt from a github/flutter issue is to open the /android folder (within the flutter project) as a standard alone "Android" project within Android Studio. The option will appear when you right-click on the /res folder.

Comment: @MwamiTovi is right, however you need to wait for gradle sync before right-clicking or even sync manually, otherwise "new -> image asset" will not show.

Comment: I can't found New>Image Asset option after right clicking on both android and android/app folder on latest version of android studio.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution actually did the trick for Android. For whatever reason, the icons generated flutter_launcher_icons were showing small in the launcher, not covering the whole thing. Maybe I missed something, but it appears as straight forward as other have mentioned, yet it didn't work. Using Android Studio worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: In the Asset Studio window I have an error saying: Project must be built with SDK 26 or later to use adaptive icons. The error prevents me for saving the icon. any approach for that?

Comment: @Taba Try opening the just `android` folder of your Flutter project using Android Studio. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778020/can-i-use-android-8-0-adaptive-icons-for-a-flutter-app

Comment: For me, when I clicked on New > Image Asset, nothing happens. For anybody having this problem, just go to File > Open, navigate to the "android" folder of your flutter project and open it. Wait for it Android Studio to sync (it took about 2 minutes for me). Once it's loaded, open the "app" folder, right click on the "res" folder, then New > Image Asset. That worked for me. (Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3512#issuecomment-516252436)

Comment: ios should be labelled "ios and macos"

Comment: For me for some reason, the gradle didn't work (currently on arctic fox) and it prompted me to download the latest 

android studio (electric-eel) after that it seems to work 

Answer (score 310):

**Follow simple steps:**

**1.** Add `flutter_launcher_icons` Plugin to `pubspec.yaml`

e.g.

```yaml
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "icon/icon.png" 
  android: true
  ios: true
  # optionally, as transparency is not allowed on app store
  # remove_alpha_ios: true
```

**2.** Prepare an app icon for the specified path.
`e.g. icon/icon.png`

**3.** Execute command on the terminal to Create app icons:

`$ flutter pub get`

`$ flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`

To check check all available options and to set different icons for android and iOS please refer [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

**Update:**

`flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.0` Version (12th Sept 2020) has **Added flavours support**

Flavors are typically used to build your app for different environments such as `dev` and `prod`

The community has written some articles and packages you might find useful. These [articles](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) address flavors for both iOS and Android.

Comment: This worked for me; only once I'd run that last line `flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I get errors android.dart:164:25: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 4 found.

Comment: I can switch icon if darkmode is activated?

Comment: @ir2pid to solve error you need to update version as flutter_launcher_icons: 0.7.5

Comment: Just a curious question: why `pub pub` instead of `pub`?

Comment: @ch271828n Updated answer. Thanks for the informing. Previously it's as per flutter documentation.

Comment: make sure your icon size is 1024x1024, or it may give error when you upload to TestFlight

Comment: I'm hitting The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again. any help?

Comment: I'm getting `FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)` even if I added `flutter_launcher_icons: 0.9.2` explicitly in the pubspec it's still says: `FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.9.1)` what can I do ?

Comment: Make sure you clean your cache and restart. Sometimes, you may need to restart the the project, uninstall that app, or restart the emulator

Comment: after i succeed , removing the plug in will be fine ?

Answer (score 50):

I have changed it in the following steps:

1. please add this dependency on your pubspec.yaml page

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
```

2. you have to upload an image/icon on your project which you want to see as a launcher icon. (i have created a folder name:image in my project then upload the logo.png in the image folder). Now you have to add the below codes and paste your image path on image_path: in pubspec.yaml page.

```yaml
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "images/logo.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
```

3. Go to terminal and execute this command:

   flutter pub get
4. After executing the command then enter below command:

   flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
5. Done

N.B: (of course add an updated dependency from

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#-installing-tab-

)

Answer (score 48):

**I would suggest You to use this website Linked Below**

[App Icon Creator](https://icon.kitchen)

Step-1: upload The Image,

Step-2: Make necessary Changes And Click on download(dont change the file name)

Step-3: Extract the Downloaded Zip File In the respective folder

```
android/app/src/main/res
```

Comment: this suggestion will not help in IOS

Comment: works for ios too using xcode to add the xassets

Comment: please how do we do this for ios

Answer (score 46):

You have to replace the Flutter icon files with images of your own. This site will help you turn your png into launcher icons of various sizes:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

Comment: Your link only produces the correct sizes for Android icons

Comment: latest website https://icon.kitchen

Answer (score 29):

**Best** & **Recommended** way to set App Icon in Flutter.

I found one plugin to set app icon in flutter named **flutter_launcher_icons**. We can use this plugin to set the app icon in flutter.

1. Add this plugin in pubspec.yaml file in project root directory. Please check below code,

```yaml
dependencies:    
 flutter:    
  sdk: flutter    
 cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2    
 flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.2+1**
```

Save the file and run flutter pub get on terminal.

2. Create a folder assets in the root of the project in folder assets also create a folder icon and place your app icon inside this folder. I will recommend to user 1024x1024 app icon size. I have placed app icon inside icon folder and now I have app icon path as assets/icon/icon.png
3. Now, in pubspec.yaml add the below code,

```yaml
flutter_icons:    
 android: "launcher_icon"    
 ios: true    
 image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

4. Save the file and run flutter pub get on terminal. After running command run second command as below

```sh
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f pubspec.yaml
```

Then Run App

Comment: Although you answered the same old correct answer, at least you highlighted the main points of that.

Comment: what does `android: "launcher_icon"` mean?

Comment: it appears me error adding flutter_launcher_icons I suggest you replace it by
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.11.0"

Answer (score 23):

Flutter has its own default icon for every app in its Android and Ios folder so there are few steps that I would like to show to change the app icon.

1. Head over to https://appicon.co/ and generate your own icon using
   icon image    (the zip file contains two main folders **android** and
   **Assets.xcassets**)
2. For android: Go inside **android\app\src\main\res** in your flutter app and there paste the android folder content.
3. For IOS: Go inside **ios\Runner** in your flutter app and there paste the Assets.xcassets
   content
4. Restart your emulator or rebuild your application

Comment: why using plugins when it is native ;)

Comment: No, I am not talking about plugins I am sharing the link to generate icons later we will use it in our native code.

Comment: I did this but My icon just looks like a square and doesn't fill the round circle. Any tips?

Comment: Hey @TenDigitGrid you can easily do that using android studio.
Open android->app->src->main->res and there right-click on res folder and then select New and then select Image Assets then you will get image assets configuration wizard. Their click on source asset path and select your icon their you will get all sorts of differrent configuration for your icon

Answer (score 16):

Without any packages

**Android**

1. Create an adaptive launcher icon in your Flutter project's root directory using the [Android Asset Studio.](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)
2. Add the generated launcher icon files to the project's `android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-*/` directories.
3. Edit the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file and add the following line below the  tag:

`<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">`

4. Run the `flutter build apk` command to generate an APK with the new launcher icon.

**iOS**

1. Create an Adaptive App Icon in your Flutter project's root directory using the [App Icon Generator](https://appicon.co/).
2. Add the generated app icon files to the project's `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/` directory.
3. Edit the `ios/Runner/Info.plist` file and add the following line below the  tag:

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

4. Run the flutter build ios command to generate an IPA with the new launcher icon.

Answer (score 15):

[flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

**Add this in your `pubspec.yaml` file**

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  # optionally, as transparency is not allowed on app store
  # remove_alpha_ios: true
```

after adding this run the below `command`

> `$ flutter pub get`

> `$ flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`

Answer (score 10):

The flutter_launcher_icons package recommended in many answers above hasn't been updated for quite some time now and is throwing an uncaught exception.

You can use the package [icons_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/icons_launcher) instead though.

1. Update the pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
  icons_launcher: ^1.1.7

flutter_icons:
  image_path: 'assets/ic_logo_border.png'
  ios: true
  android: true
```

2. Run the package

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run icons_launcher:main
```

Answer (score 7):

Best way is to change launcher icons separately for both iOS and Android.

Change the icons in iOS and Android module separately. 
The plugin produces different size icons from the same icon which are distorted.

Follow this link:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps:-

**1.** Add dependencies of **flutter_luncher_icons** in **pubspec.yaml** file.You can find this plugin from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons).

**2.** Add your required images in **asstes folder** and **pubspec.yaml** file as below .

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: NewsApi.org
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
      sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  toast: ^0.1.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/newsicon.png"
  android: true
  ios: false

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/dropbox.png



  fonts:
    - family: LangerReguler
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/langer_reguler.ttf




  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**3.** Then run the command in terminal  **flutter pub get** and then **flutter_luncher_icon**.This is what  I get the  result after the successfully run the command . And luncher icon is also generated successfully.

**My Terminal**

```
[E:\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterProject\NewsFlutter\news_flutter>flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in news_flutter...                       881ms

E:\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterProject\NewsFlutter\news_flutter>flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.8.0)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════

• Creating default icons Android
• Overwriting the default Android launcher icon with a new icon

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
```

Answer (score 6):

I use few methods for chaging flutter app lancher icon but only the manuall method is a bit easy and good. Because you will know how it work.

So to change flutter ios icon. First get copy of your icon 1024×1024 pixel and generate set of icons for android and ios using easyappicon generator.
When you get zip file it work create two folder ios and android open ios folder and copy folder and replace the one in your ios/runner directory.

For android copy all folder present in android folder and replace the ones present in the android/app/src/main/res/drawable here.

After replacing folder on both ios and android stop the app and re run and your icons will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

-- first go to :- https://www.appicon.co/
this website and generate your app logo.
-- after that you got a two folder one android and second IOS.
-- after that you can go this folder directory
android -> app -> src -> main -> res
then after you can replace all folder to generated new logo folder.
after that it can been change in android app.

-- after that you can go this folder directory
IOS -> runner
and replace <Assets.xcassets> this folder to generated new logo folder.
after that it can been changed in IOS app.

-- then after if you need change native screen image so follow this step.
first go to IOS folder and press right class and open your project in x
code.
-- after that you can go in runner folder and move to assert image folder.
-- after that you can see 1x, 2x and 3x image.
-- you can change it new image according to 1x, 2x and 3x image.

-- after that you got a successfully change logo in both add with native scree.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to appicon.co (App Icon Generator)
- Drag and drop the app icon image which we want to be the app’s icon.
- Add file name => ic_launcher and click generate
- A file named AppIcons.zip gets downloaded.
- Extract it and we will get two folders: **android** and **Assets.xcassets**.
- Now replace the respective files from respective folders from the project:

  1. for Android, Go to android>app>src>main>res> and replace files from android folder which we have extracted.
  2. for iOS, Go to ios>Runner> and replace the Assets.xcassets folder with the extracted one.
- So, In this way, we can add app icons to our flutter android & ios application.