# changing Launcher icon flutter error

Tags: gradle, dart, flutter

I was trying to change the Launcher icon in flutter and got this error: failed processing manifest.   Failed to execute aapt
[image: failed processing manifest. Failed to execute aapt]

I did not even know there is a second manifest file located in another folder according to that log file. am new to flutter

Comment: Please add the information where you put the icon file and how the change looks like you made to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: When asking, please insert formatted error message/stack, not screenshot, so it can be indexed, became searchable and is easier to read.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I first tried to change the icons. So I deleted the defaults and replaced with new ones. The error came up so I reverted back to the default icons and the error still remains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ***android*** folder (look at the screenshot), replace ALL icons and update the name CORRECTLY under AndroidManifest.xml file

[image]

Comment: This is exactly as is in the project

Comment: Try "flutter clean" and run again?

Comment: No. I ended up creating a new project and transferring all my work there. Afresh

Answer (score 0):

To **change the icon of the two applications**, I recommend you use this add-on:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

1º Add dependency to your Flutter project's pubspec.yaml below any existing dependencies

2º Within the same pubspec.yaml file, add flutter_icons config section

```
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

   flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.3.2"

   flutter_icons:
   image_path: "icon/icon.png" 
   android: true
   ios: "Example-Icon"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid `pubspec.yaml` entry.

Comment: @KevinRobert I've provided an example on the GitHub project page for the Flutter Launcher Icons package: https://github.com/franzsilva/flutter_launcher_icons/tree/master/example