# Can I use Android 8.0 Adaptive Icons for a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, adaptive-icon

How can I use an Adaptive Icon for my Flutter app on Android 8.0 and up? The Create Image Asset dialog in Android Studio says "Project must be built with SDK 26 or later to use adaptive icons", even though [my android build.gradle](https://github.com/piggehperson/flip_flutter/blob/master/android/app/build.gradle) has CompileSDKVersion set to 27. If I define the icon in XML, it doesn't work, it seems to just use the regular legacy app icon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They work perfectly fine.

### Solution

*To work with the dialog*, you will need to open your *Android module* in Android Studio.
[Flutter.dev article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#android-ide)

Navigation is the following in the menu bar: `Tools` ~> `Flutter` ~> `Open Android module in Android Studio` or right-click anywhere in your `android` folder in the project view and select `Flutter` ~> `Open Android module in Android Studio`.

*Now you **will be able** to use the asset dialog normally*.

#### If it still does not work (this does not happen)

If your dialog *does not work* in your **Flutter project**, you can easily create an *adaptive icon* in an **Android project** and then copy the necessary file, which are:

- `ic_launcher_background.xml` (drawable), I think that this is located in *values* if you chose a color
- `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` (drawable-v24)
- `ic_launcher.xml` and if you created it `ic_launcher_round.xml` (mipmap-anydpi-v26)
- all `ic_launcher.png` and `ic_launcher_round.png` (mipmap-hdpi to mipmap-xxxhdpi) for legacy support. I suppose that these are not needed if your minimum SDK requirement is higher than *25*

This would cover everything for me. Now, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` specify `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` for your application, i.e. in your `<application>` tag, and if needed `android:roundIcon:"@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`.

Comment: isn't that a bug that one should open the project _again_ in a different mode for that to work consistently?

Comment: `New -> Image asset` menu was not visible for me when android module is opened. It only appeared after a successful gradle sync, which had failed for me due to a dependency issue.

Comment: @Lahiru Candima how I can use gradle sync in my flutter project. I have made my project in VSCode but when I import it in Andriod Studio 4.1.1 it gives me the error `this project is not gradle base`. I even tried creating the project in Andriod studio but it does not give me a gradle sync option. Every time I have to import the project again in Andriod Studio to give me the sync option but it still gave me `the not gradle based project` error. It does not also give me android module.