# How can i use xml icons to my flutter application

Tags: xml, flutter, icons

I want to use some specific icons from my older application in Xamarin on my new app in Flutter. Is there any way how can i get my XML icons to the new one ?

Comment: These icons were only used for android? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778020/can-i-use-android-8-0-adaptive-icons-for-a-flutter-app and does this help?

Comment: Yes, only for android. No it doesn't