# How to access "Configure Image Asset"

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I want to manipulate my App's icon using "Image Asset Studio", usually I start it by following [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access):

1- In the Project window, select the Android view.

2- Right-click the **res** folder and select **New > Image Asset**...

so I reach this window:

[image]

but for some reason **I don't see this option "Image Asset"** at the "New" menu.

> **NOTE:** If I create a new project then I can see "New > Image Asset" normally.

**Update**:

I'm clicking on this directory.
[image]

I run this android studio on **Ubuntu 18.04**:

> Android Studio 3.5
>   Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
>   JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Linux 4.15.0-62-generic

[image]

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-add-app-launcher-icons-in-flutter-bd92b0e0873a) article. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter) SO question.

Comment: @Eugene just see the update, thanks

Comment: @Eugene yes, with Intellij theme. but other team developers use vscode, does this affect my android studio?

Comment: @Eugene I posted the version with the OS. thanks

Comment: **NOTE:** If I create a new project then I can see "New > Image Asset" normally.

Answer (score 7):

There is actually [an issue filed in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3512) related to this.

In your case, it seems that you treat a Flutter project as a regular Android project. AFAIK, Flutter projects are not Android projects.

So [one of the workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3512#issuecomment-516252436) is also available:

> open android studio File->Open folder->navigate to your flutter
> project and select the Android folder. Wait for it to sync, then
> navigate inside the Android studio folder and find the res folder
> right click on it and choose New you will see the Image asset studio.

Also take note of [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3512#issuecomment-524566270):

> don't open the whole project of flutter using Android studio just open
> the android folder found inside the flutter project with Android
> studio, so the Android studio can treat it as a Android project rather
> than flutter project, which will give you all Android features like
> the one ur looking for #image asset studio

And you can also check [this blog post](https://medium.com/techiee/flutter-changing-app-icons-2d0646580a62) about changing your Flutter app icons. And this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpQenyqxTmw). You will only need your desired image for the icon and [App Icon Generator](https://appicon.co/).

To summarize what was written in the blog and discussed in the YouTube post, here are the simple steps you need to follow:

**Step 1:** Visit [appicon.co](https://appicon.co/) and upload your intended image to convert to icons, select the types you would like to be generated and click “generate”. This will download a zip folder to your system. (You may skip this step if you have all resolutions in place with you.)

[image]

**Step 2:** Unzip the file. You’ll have two folders by the name of “android” and “*Assets.xcassets*”.

[image]
[image]

**Step 3:** Changing icons for Android App.
In your Flutter project, move to **android/app/src/main/res** which has a lot of folders starting with “*mipmap-*”. Delete all of them. And replace from your downloaded and unzipped AppIcons folder, everything that’s under android.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

if you right click on res folder and Image Asset is not enabled just follow the following steps they are working for me.

File --> Open and select to open android(which is inside your project) in a new window.
Then if you go to the res folder (on the new window) and right click the Image Asset is enabled.

[image]

[image]