# I can't find the Image Asset option in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I started learning App development in Android Studio, using the Flutter UI toolkit. Everything seems fine, however when i want to create a **New Image Asset** to edit my app's icon, i can't find it. When i right-click the *android/app/src/main/res* folder, it does not appear within *New*. I am following some older tutorials and they all have that option there.

This is what comes up:
[image]

My version of Android Studio is:

[image]

And my version of Flutter is: 2.8.1 (Dart 2.15.1)

How can i fix this, or are there any alternatives for modifying my app's icon?

Answer (score 10):

For **Flutter** users: If you created the Android project via `flutter create`, make sure to open the Android Studio project in the `android` subfolder, not the one in the root folder. Then, Android Studio should automatically run gradle. Once this has finished (which can take quite some time on the first run), the Android Studio UI should automatically switch to the "Android View", and the "New > Image Asset" option should become available for the `res` folder. No need to manually mark anything.

Just make sure that gradle runs through, otherwise the *real* "Android View" won't be available, even if it is selected.

Answer (score 5):

Does it work for you? If that doesn't work, try right-clicking the drawable folder and selecting "New" -> "Image Asset".

[image: tools menu]

[image: resource manager screen]

Comment: I can't find Resource Management either, not under Tools or anywhere. the option "Show In Resource Manager" appears when I Right-Click the res folder and is clickable, but nothing happens when I click on it. When I search for Image Asset in Help -> FInd Action, it is listed as a disabled action.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to come up when I right click on the root node of the project (a flutter project) and selected `flutter` -> `Open Android module in Android Studio`
Then I was able to right click the `res` folder and clicked on `new` -> `Image Asset`

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue and this suggestion really helped me. Hope this will help you too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773774/20910266

To me the key point is this:

"don't open the whole project of flutter using Android studio just open the android folder found inside the flutter project with Android studio, so the Android studio can treat it as a Android project rather than flutter project, which will give you all Android features like the one ur looking for #image asset studio".

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

Right click on `res` directory -> Choose `Mark Directory as` -> `Resources root`

[image: Right click -> Mark Directory as -> Resourses root]

If it is not working, try to change file view to `Android`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've seen this before as you're using Flutter. Despite all the answers, I'd recommend you to right-click the `android/` folder from your Flutter app root and select **Mark as... > Project Root**, then close and reopen the project in Android Studio.

If Android finally recognizes this as an Android project, it will take a long, long time to download some of the project's dependencies (in which some of them are already downloaded through `flutter pub get` and `flutter run`/`build`. After it's ready, the project files will be finally available for you, including the option to launch the Image Asset Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Update To Latest Version Frist.

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Visit https://developer.android.com/ And Download Manually And Install.

After You Can Find Res/New_resources_deirectory/midmap

It's Very Simple.

#Android_Studio

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in that Image Assets didn't show up.

I recognised that the root folder for my project was the react-native project folder, and not the `android` folder.

**Solution**: Open android studio project from the android folder

[Android Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss2FN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Go to `File` > `Open` > `yourandroidfolder` > `this window`

wait for the gradle build to complete

**NOTE AFTER THIS YOU MIGHT NEED TO UPGRADE AGP**