# Failed to handle method call on local notification

Tags: android, flutter, notifications

I'm testing out this [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-readme-tab-) plugin for local notifications. I want to show a notification on a button press, this is my code:

```
FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin localNotifPlugin =
                  new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
              var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  'default',
                  'Test App Notifications',
                  'Channel for default notifications from test app');
              var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
              var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
                  androidChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);
              localNotifPlugin.show(
                  0,
                  "Test Notificaiton",
                  "This is your test notification! :)",
                  platformChannelSpecifics);
            },
            child: Text("Show Notification"),
          )
```

This is very similar to the documentation for the plugin but its not working and I'm getting this error when I press the button:

```
    D/EGL_emulation(24401): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa80053c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8003360)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setSmallIcon(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:156)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:131)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:598)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:690)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:619)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:656)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/MethodChannel#dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications(24401):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
E/flutter (24401): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference, null)
E/flutter (24401): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (24401): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
E/flutter (24401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24401): #2      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications.dart:120:20)
E/flutter (24401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24401): #3      HomePage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:provider_test/main.dart:53:36)
E/flutter (24401): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:654:14)
E/flutter (24401): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:729:32)
E/flutter (24401): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (24401): #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
E/flutter (24401): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
E/flutter (24401): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)
E/flutter (24401): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:75:13)
E/flutter (24401): #11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:102:11)
E/flutter (24401): #12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (24401): #13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (24401): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (24401): #15     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (24401): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (24401): #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (24401): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (24401): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (24401): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:263:10)
E/flutter (24401): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:172:5)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like you are initializing plugin without or with wrong app_icon;

In your initState you should initialize with CORRECT ICON NAME:

```
@override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
   var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon'); // <- default icon name is @mipmap/ic_launcher
   var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
   var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
   flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification); }
```

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications#getting-started <- how to initialize

[How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter) <- adding app icons

Comment: I've added the app icon through flutter launcher icon plugin, also added the code you mentioned to my widget, But I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/Wr3iNs0v also I've tried '@mipmap/ic_launcher doesn't work

Comment: Please use full code in the init method. https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications#getting-started my answer only contained a snippet of it

Comment: @AmolBorkar maybe too late but just make sure you are actually initializing the plugin. I was getting the same error turns out I wrote the function to initialize the plugin but I never called it.

Answer (score 9):

I solve the problem by indicating the file type when initializing android setting as follows:

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon.png');
```

Alternatively, u can set the icon as default like this:

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when there is error in initialization mainly because of app icon. Provide mipmap/ic_launcher or filename.png when initialising (filename.png is preferred). Otherwise you might have not called or wait for the initialization. Use await before calling onMessage listener.

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
);

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Message body: ${message.notification.body}');}
```