# Unable to set Launcher Icon in Flutter Project in Android Studio 4.0.1

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to set launcher icons for Android through New > Image Asset and I don't see the option anymore. I believe this is a recent change in Android Studio as I used to do it until a few months ago by right-clicking the res folder to add New > Image Asset. How do I set the icons in Android Studio 4.0.1?

I wanted to see if Resource Manager would be of any help but it remains stuck with a message **"Waiting for build to finish..."**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link if trying to change the icon of your app:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter`

Comment: Thanks mate! I tried that, but it does not allow me to set the size/position of the icon, etc. and it just sets a default dimension. New > Image Asset allowed users to dynamically enlarge or downsize the size of the icon in various icon shapes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up creating a new empty native android project for just creating the launch icons. And then I just copied them to my Flutter project.

(After creating the icons via the resource manager, you can right click on them and clicking "show in explorer" will lead you directly to the folder. So it is easy to copy and paste from there on.)