# How to duplicate my own created flutter project with new one

Tags: flutter, new-project

I've a flutter project in Visual Studio Code uploaded in git too. Now I want to create a new project with different package and AppName by changing existing one. How can I do that? hope you guys understand what I am talking about.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You can use [rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package to rename your appname and packagename and bundle id and everything.
Just install it globaly so you can use it everywhere.

`flutter pub global activate rename`

Then navigate to your project directory and change the bundleId (package name) and appname:

```
flutter pub global run rename --bundleId com.onatcipli.networkUpp
flutter pub global run rename --appname "Network Upp"
```

You can also make a copy of your project before doing all this, so you can have both versions.

**Changing the app icon**

If you want to change the app icon as well, use this method after renaming:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52829977/5423747

**What I do**

Usually I have to remake same package for different organizations. I have a main project in git is stable branch, then I make new branch from stable branch and repeat the methods above.

Comment: would be change the package name too?

Comment: The bundleId is same as the package name. (the first line)

Comment: _then I make new branch from stable branch and repeat the methods above_ -just wanted to ask, isn't it better to create a new repository, rather than creating lots of new branches?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal My app is being used by more than 30 organizations, managing repositories would be really hard. And for every update, I don't have to update each repository one by one. In each branch I just change the API base URL and I get the organization info (like the name, icon, color, auth data and ... ) from the (API base URL + /config).

Comment: Oh i see..
In that case, that decision is great, but on my case every project have different request and demand, even though the program itself have its base code

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Then I'd suggest making your base code a package/sdk so the new features and updates would apply on all your projects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the program itself is a full custom, so it's possible that the package/sdk maybe will also be full customized too, soo yeah, i think i will customize it only to changes requested..