# Change App Logo in Flutter with png or jpeg?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the logo of my app but I dont know whats the right format to use. For Example when my Logo is the Apple logo. Should I use a jpeg file with a background color or should I only use a png of the Apple and add a background color later on?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [chage the application launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52829977/14343554)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are standards for everything, when you are in a confusion you should always look for those.

iOS's standards:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Android's standards:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Answer (score 3):

Flutter Launcher Icons has been designed to help quickly generate launcher icons.

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

- Add the package to your pubspec.yaml file (within your Flutter project) to use it.
- Within pubspec.yaml file, specify the path of the icon you wish to use for the app.
- Run the package.

Answer (score 0):

mipmap folder to change image in android app logo change [image]

Answer (score 0):

Uploading your application to App Store normally requires a jpg with a background, or a png with extra configuration line in case you use flutter_launcher_icons as suggested above  -  Setting "remove_alpha_ios: true" to remove it.