# How to change app icon in flutter using VS Code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

How to change the app icon in `Flutter` using `VS Code`?

I am trying it again and again but it's not working. I've seen different methods online with no positive outcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of flutter plugin you may change flutter icon package:

flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

- Step 1:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

- Step 2:

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the **flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2** package

Create new folder named *assets* and a subfolder inside that named *icon* then make changes in your pubspec.yaml file like following:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

Here the icon image should be icon.png and it will be stored in the path : assets/icon

now in terminal run

```
flutter pub get
```

for further info check [this](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons) as reference. And this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VGlLjBxYQ4&ab_channel=ProGrammer) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use current method **Flutter Launcher Icons**.

1. Edit *pubspec.yaml* file:

> ```
> dev_dependencies:
>   flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.10.0"
>
> flutter_icons:
>   android: "launcher_icon"
>   ios: true
>   image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
>   min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
>   web:
>     generate: true
>     image_path: "path/to/image.png"
>     background_color: "#hexcode"
>     theme_color: "#hexcode"
>   windows:
>     generate: true
>     image_path: "path/to/image.png"
>     icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
> ```

2. Go to Terminal:

> ```
> flutter pub get
> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
> ```

Have a nice day...

Source: [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons][1]

Comment: Thanks, I was missing `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`