# How to set custom image icon on Flutter App? Using Appicon

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

I Tried changing my app's Icon on apk but it's not changing. I generated an icon on https://appicon.co/ and try changing but it's showing flutter's default app icon.

Comment: flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2 use this plugin

Comment: There are many answers availabe Check thelink
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43928702/11789675

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

In pubsec.yaml

```
 dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.10.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
```

And then run this on your terminal (from android studio)

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

The command will regenerate icons for android and ios. You can check it in the corresponding folders (eg for android : app/src/main/res/drawable-xxx/ic_launcher)

Comment: what do `android: "launcher_icon"` and `android: true` mean?

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming from the future and you have difficulty using the flutter_launcher_icons package.

In July 2022, I tried using the flutter_launcher_icons package (version: "**^0.9.2**") but it did not work when running the

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

and got the famous error **255** code.

After a little search on google, I came across this (very short) and followed this article here: https://www.codewithflutter.com/how-to-change-application-launcher-icon-in-flutter/.

This is what I did to get a launcher icon for the devices that my app would run on.
It's a simple 3 step method to change the app launcher icon.

**Step 1:**

Go to https://appicon.co/ and use select your launcher's image file.

For best results, it should be **1024 x 1024** pixels.
Select the devices for which you would like the app icon to be generated for. Click on the "**Generate**" button and a zip file would be downloaded.

When you open the downloaded zip file, it would normally contain the "**android**" and the "**Assets.xcassets**" folders (assuming you are generating for both android and ios devices).

**Step 2:**

***Changing the icons manually.***

This process is just copying and pasting the folders.

**For android:**

Open the **AppIcons\Android** folder and copy all the sub folders.
Then go the `android\app\src\main\res` folder and paste it (replace the existing file to new files).

**For ios:**

Open the AppIcons folder and copy the `Assets.xcassets` folder.
Then go the `ios/Runner` and paste it (replace the existing file to new files).

**Step 3:**

Run the command `flutter run`

Thank you!