# Flutter android 12 icon

Tags: flutter, icons, padding, android-12, flutter-android

does anyone konow, how to change this ring around the Icon while changing apps? It is everywhere in a diffent colors, like the settings[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xaf0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is because in android apps icons have a foreground and background. This is referenced here in this question. Might be helpful! [How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter)