# Change Flutter Launcher Icon

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web, dart-html

I want to Change Flutter Install Icon

If you check the "Chrome PWA install" link from my post. You can see that i encircled the icon. i wanted to change the default flutter icon to my own icon.

[Chrome PWA install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si5za.png)
[Chrome Apllication/manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU3zo.png)

Comment: what is your issue? , what do you want to achieve ? and what is your question?

Comment: Hello @pmatatias

If you check the "Chrome PWA install" link from my post. You can see that i encircled the icon. i wanted to the default flutter icon to my own icon.

Comment: i mean, please describe more details.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: This post answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652788/11941095

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all Add `flutter_launcher_icons` Plugin from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to `pubspec.yaml`.
then Prepare an app icon for the specified path `e.g. icon/icon.png`.
after that Execute command on the terminal to Create app icons.
first `$ flutter pub get`
then `$ flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`.
at the end To check all available options and to set different icons for android and iOS please refer [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons).

Comment: This worked. Thanks. i did saw this before but i didnt use it because the package platform web is not indicated. may be they just havent updated.

Answer (score 11):

1. Simple, go to this website https://appicon.co/ and upload your icon
2. It will give you a zip file simple export it and look for Android & Asset.xcassets
3. Go to `android/app/src/main/res` and replace everything with the android folder in a zip file (For Android)
4. Go to `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets` and replace everything with Assets.xcassets folder in a zip file (For iOS)
5. Remove the app from your device, run `flutter clean` & then `flutter run`

Comment: On point 4, replace only these folders: android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi