# flutter app icon don't change while replaced icons manually to res folder

Tags: flutter, android-studio, icons

i want to change the icon of the flutter app to a picture .i put it on appicon.co-
and simply replace the icons into my project as you can see in picture but it doesnt work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmLfE.png)
please give me a hint where am i wrong?
windows 11
android studio dolphin 2021
thanks

Comment: I suggest using [this packace](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons).

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See answer from previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652788/9063088

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the application launcher icon on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928702/how-to-change-the-application-launcher-icon-on-flutter)