# setting up an iOS app logo via Plist not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having a problem setting up a logo that will be displayed on the home screen of an iPhone for an iOS app I am creating.

I have gone in info.plist->information property list and added icon files. In the icon files, I added a logo.png file which is in the same directory level as info.plist.

However, when I save and run my app I can't see the logo that I added. The app still shows as shown in the image and not with the logo icon I just added. is there something more I need to do?

[image: Application without Logo Image]

Comment: You need to add the icon file in your Assets.xcassets-> Appicon, Also make sure App icons source is set in Targets. Please follow this link for more info  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32136202/4549304

Comment: Please check App Icons source in general tab of target settings. Set it to don't use assets catalog if you don't want to use Assets.xcassets.