# ios App Icon is missing in the simulator using react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image: I have added all the icons to their respective places.]
[image]
[image: I added this script that I found in another post but no luck.]

[image]

I added the script that I found in another post but no luck. I cleaned the build folder hundred times but nothing is working.

Comment: refere this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170520/ios-how-to-set-app-icon-and-launch-images

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned but to no avail.

In Icon Set Creator:

Drag your image into the view
Choose your target platform
Export the Icon Set folder
iconSetCreator

In XCode:

Navigate to the Assets.xcassets Folder
Delete the pre existing AppIcon
Right click -> Import your created Icon-Set as AppIcon and you're done

Answer (score 10):

Actually in my case the target has been set correctly. All I needed to do was to turn off the simulator and let it get started by the build again.

Comment: This fixed the issue on my end, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Have you checked the "Target Membership" in the right-side pane?

> 1. Go to "images.xcassets" under your project
> 2. Click "AppIcon" or any image asset you have for your project
> 3. Show the Inspector on the right
> 4. See if "Target Membership" is checked correctly for your app.

[image: XCode Inspectors Window]

Comment: this is disabled in my xcode

Answer (score 2):

Select Target from Xcode then navigate to General Tab and under "App Icon and Launch Images" section select "App Icons Source" -> AppIcon

Answer (score 0):

It was greyed out in the Target membership. I fixed that and it worked.