# Ideal image size for iOS

Tags: ios, xcasset

If I want to display an icon with 24x24 in an app, what sizes should I provide in the app?

For example, is it sufficient to save the image as 128x128 in the app?

Or are **@1x @2x @3x** sizes required?

It is a simple icon (width == height), example:

[image: example icon]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App icon size for new iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819441/app-icon-size-for-new-ios)

Comment: @xfix The duplicate you've linked is about app icons and not assets in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different sizes are not necessarily required, but they can help reducing binary sizes.

For an image that you want to show in the dimensions of **24x24**, you should provide a **24x24**, a **48x48** and a **72x72** image.

For simple graphics like this, it's usually more suitable if you [create a vector asset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25818845/3151675).