# Sizes and names on icons and launch images in Xcode 5, ios 7

Tags: icons, ios7, launch, xcode5

I recently downloaded xcode 5 and work now for ios 7. How do I add Icon-images to the project now? What is the sizes that I need and do they have to have specific names?
I also want to know this things about the launch images.
I have searched on google and stuff but I find different answers and I want to know the right answer.
I do also wonder if I put this icons in my project for ios 7 does it work for those who have ios 6?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by reading Apples iOS 7 documentation and the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174).

Comment: Have you tried to look at Xcode? The dimensions are right there in the ["General" section of your target](http://i.imgur.com/pWxxGEQ.png).

Comment: Check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons/18785001#18785001

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) the guidelines iOS for all icons and the new guidelines for iOS 7 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

and [Here](http://makeappicon.com/) a website to create all size of your icons for iOS 6, 7 and Android with the 1024*1024.

Comment: The guidelines link are currently outdated for iOS 7. Try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: Great link to the tool that creates the different sizes - big time saver!

Comment: That website is really perfect tool