# no image with correct dimensions found of icon 120 x 120

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7

[image: this is app icon setting image where we can set icon][image: this is image dimensions 120 x 120]

I am adding image of correct dimensions of 120 x 120 but still showing error 
and apple reject may app.

I also try to add icon to info.plist file but still not working.

My app developed in xcode 4.6 and i try to change icon in xcode 5. is any problematic in this?

Answer (score 2):

Just select image from your bundle which has size is 120 x 120...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but i try same thing but still not adding image. My image is 120 x 120 but showing that not correct dimension. actully 120 x 120 is correct.

Comment: Check this link http://makeappicon.com/# add your high resolution icon and u get all icon in proper size for ios 7 , 6, android . Then i think u issue will be solve .

Answer (score 1):

You need to browse and select new image you want to add according to its dimensions in table. You need to re-layout the asset catalog for new images.

Here is already an answer, describing in detail:
[iOS 7 App Icons, Launch images And Naming Convention While Keeping iOS 6 Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons)

Answer (score 1):

maybe "YourApp-info.plist" file has problem. check it. i have same problem and i found problem in "YourApp-info.plist" file. in my problem that file deleted before and new location of file was incorrect.