# iOS 7 retina and normal image naming convention

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

i am using Xcode 5 and developing a Application which will have deployment target "7.0" so do i need to add the Normal image and retina images both ... or i can just use the normal image naming convention with Double Resolution (Retina images).i mean can we avoid "@2x" from file name for all the application targeted only for the Retina devices.

For e.g.:
suppose i have background image named with resolution of **640x960** so should i use "**bg.png**" or "**bg@2x.png**"?

FYI: i don't want to include normal resolution image because i am not targeting any non-retina devices

Any help will be Greatly appreciated , thanks in Advance!

Comment: The iPad2 runs with iOS7 and isn't retina. So I guess you should respect this naming convention for people who will install your app (even if it's an iPhone app) on their iPad2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael and pointing the valid point! i also want to know if i use Retina image with "@2x" convention, than will it scale it down to normal resolution while running it on iPad 2 ?

Comment: That’s a good question ! Since i didn’t know the answer, i removed a non-retina reference, clean the project, deleted the app and run it again : the image was visible, so the retina image must have been scaled down.
You can test it with the Ipad Non-Retina simulator.

Comment: Consider using `Asset Catalog`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons/18785001#18785001

Answer (score 1):

App rejected if your app not support for iPhone 5 and 5s, 5c devices. because these device are built in retina and coming iPhone model devices are mode up with retina display.

so target to all iPhone device size

retina device automatically detected with image name @2x. so you must use @2x.png in your image name string

If you need to support standard-resolution iPhone or iPod touch devices, divide by 2 the high-resolution sizes listed below.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: Thanks for your answer iDev! but can you please provide me your views on following: if i use Retina image with "@2x" convention, than will it scale it down to normal resolution while running it on iPad 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

If your deployment target is only **"7.0"** then you does not need to add both image, just add only retina images with name **"bg@2x.png"**  here **"@2x"** is must require because retina device only recognize image with end of **"@2x"**.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xcassets` can be very helpful in making image sets for different screen sizes. You should make new image set and select screen sizes you would like to support. See image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9dowakx4n8x58i/Screenshot%202014-02-26%2009.47.17.png.
There you can just drag and drop appropriate assets to **1x**, **2x** or **R4** fields.

I believe that you should be "a good citizen" and support smaller screen sizes (like @Michaël Azevedo stated).

Answer (score 0):

You better to use normal image name as **bg.png** and retina image name as **bg@2x.png**. because there is updation to iOS 7.0 and above is possible for non retina devices also