# Application update from ios6 to ios7 doesn't replace the previous app icons and launch image with the new images

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, xcode5, launchimage

I have an iOS6/iOS7 application in the App Store which is going to be replaced with the new version of the App. The new version includes new app icons and a new launch image. 
My problem is that the old app icons and the launch image are not replaced with the update.
This only works when I delete the old app before I install the new app.
Any ideas how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check to see if you have followed all the naming conventions or not. Refer to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons

Comment: Is this issue on device or iOS Simulator? Sometimes simulator may cache image resources.

Comment: you should go to project setting-->general-->launch Images and check there.

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali Great overview! But didn't help me :)

Comment: @nucleus I get this issue on both, the simulator and on the devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check wheter the images are added to the target.
Check through the cloud by uploading two ipa files and installing through safari.

Comment: My Images.xcassets was already added to the target... Additinaly, I added the app icons again and the launch image too. (iOS6 Devices)--> Now the launch image get updated, but the app icon is still the old one. (iOS7 Devices)--> The app icon and the launch image get updated but, when I launch the app then the app icon switch to the old one and back. This means, I see the new icon on the home screen, but when I touch it then it changes to the old app icon. When I resume the app the new icon is again there. Strange behavior...