# where did the icons/launch image table go in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

If you look at this thread
[iOS 7 App Icons, Launch images And Naming Convention While Keeping iOS 6 Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons)

You see that xcode used to show a nice table where you could see all icon/launch image dimensions, what is missing etc.

I just managed to start migrating our app to ios8/iphone6 so i also upgraded xcode. However, now i can't seem to locate that table anymore, all there is is an empty section with buttons to "use asset catalog": [image]
So, i have 2 questions:

1. is the table somewhere else, or is "asset catalog" the way to go now?
2. I tried the asset catalog, and all images are copied into this xcassets catalog. Is there any reason for me to keep the original files in the project? Do i need it for anything else, like ios5? I looked around but found no answer.

Thankful for some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the **Asset catalog** , this is the preferred way now.
2. If you use the asset catalog, all the images will be copied to images.xcassets, there is no need to keep the original files. If you control click the assets and show in finder, you could find the copied images. In asset catalog you have options to give different images for iOS 5,6,7 landscpae or portrait  whatever is appropriate for your app.

   [image]

Comment: Ah, sweet. It seems a little bit strange to me, if asset catalog is preferred, that they just removed the old table? How do people sort this out if they don't use the asset catalog?

Comment: I couldnt find it in Xcode 6. I think the older way will work now also if you have given proper names for the launch image, and the name for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus is not mentioned anywhere to my knowledge.Then one more, its not a sudden removal in Xcode 5 they have given time to try out the new thing. So i would recommend you to go with asset catalog:)

Comment: Thanks man. So, what you're saying is that the nice table where you actually could see what the images sizes are supposed to be is nowhere anymore, not even in asset catalog? That's a shame.

Comment: In asset catalog you can see the exact image size that you are supposed to use. Cant you see?

Comment: Click any of the placeholder, goto the attribute inspector. There expected size you can see

Comment: No, you could see that before adding images also

Comment: Thanks, when i clicked ios8, the "holes" popped up and it became clearer.