# App Icon has Unassigned Image error

Tags: xcode, xcode6, apple-watch

**I'm getting these errors:**

[image]

**I can't tell exactly which thing it is talking about?**

[image]

**If it is a 42 mm 2x, then I don't have a spot to put that.  Can you help?  Thanks!**

[image]

EDIT:
Per comment below, I looked on the right pane.  Looks like it needs the 44 2x...

[image]

[image]

...so I have one created, but the `Unassigned` doesn't highlight when I drag the icon over it, so how do I assign it in my image assets?

[image]

EDIT again:
Right click show in finder?
[image]

Comment: Please look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons/22353990#22353990

Comment: @msmq thanks for the response, please see my edit, because I can't drag the needed icon into the `Unassigned` image part for some reason.  And I believe I have the correct image size and everything?

Comment: Try by right click and select Show in Finder option and just add that icon there; Hopefully, it will be fixed.

Comment: I added an image above, I'm not sure how I'd click Show in Finder because its grayed out?

Comment: Just try this with some other icon; because, location will be same for all the icons.

Comment: If its asking for a 44 2x icon (which maybe it isn't) I already have it in that folder?

Comment: you need to add 88x88 icon in that folder.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had the same issue! The solution that worked for me was pretty easy:

Just **select** the *unassigned image* and **delete** it via delete button. **Clean** and **Build**. Done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you delete something via backslash exactly?  I've never heard of that before? @Bernard

Comment: @SRMR backslash means delete button on your keyword mate.

Comment: I can't find solution more easier than it :).

Comment: Thanks @esvau for the help!

Comment: how you are getting image back after deleting, I have 100 images in the assets so do i need to reset all by doing this?

Answer (score 4):

(That's assuming you didn't miss any of the required images)

I had this problem a while ago: I went into the `media.xcassets` directory and checked the `contents.json` file, where I found some entry with `"unassigned"` set to TRUE. I removed it and it removed the compiler warning.

Hope you got stuck in that same scenario so you will also be able to fix it.

Comment: I do see that in my `contents.json` file, when you say "I removed it" what do you mean by that, like remove the image in Xcode or edit that json file or something else?  Thanks!

Comment: I had something like { "idiom" : "universal", "unassigned" : true } which I removed from the contents.json file.

Comment: I have: `    {
      "size" : "44x44",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "unassigned" : true,
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "42mm"
    }`

Comment: But if I remove that, is it removing something important I need because it has to do with some sort of `appLauncher` icon that will need to be there?

Comment: Nothing "needed", as 44x44@2x are flagged as optional in the official docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html  But I understand it could be better for you to look for a less of a workaround solution before resolving to this one. In my scenario it had something to do with a Car App/Car UI icon (also optional), so I was glad to remove that since I didn't need to support anything like that.

Comment: These are in the WatchKit part, does the doc speak to those too?

Comment: I'm assuming deleting the `Unassigned` with the delete button would be the same thing as editing the json file right?

Comment: It couldn't be done from the GUI at that time: I guess now we can.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering why I need the 38mm 40 app launcher but wouldn't need the 42mm 44 app launcher, it makes sense that I'd need both right?

Comment: `    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "watch",
      "scale" : "2x",
      "filename" : "Icon-40@2x.png",
      "role" : "appLauncher",
      "subtype" : "38mm"
    },`

Comment: Did you try to "manually" route the json to an image file with the right characteristics? I would try that and see what happens, maybe it's a GUI bug you've hit.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense too I'll try that!

Answer (score 2):

I had to

- right click on one of the images in the lower row (with "unassigned" written under the row)
- select "Universal" to unselect it
- right click and
- "Universal" again to select it

  - This changed the top row to show 3 empty boxes that were empty
- Drag each of the images from the unassigned row to the universal row

Though, I don't know why those menu options are disabled in the original question...

Answer (score 1):

Remove all "unassigned" photos from the asset catalog. It shouldn't appear there (click "Remove Selected Items" on your screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

I had old icon files (no longer needed) in the folder where contents.json is located. I removed those files in Finder and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

My case is:
My Macbook is running out of memory, so every time I restart the computer. I don't understand how the icloud driver erased or replaced all the data in the `Contents.json` file in the folder:

`Runner> Assets.xcassets> AppIcon.appiconset` (I dev with Flutter).

So the solution for my case is I have to bring the Contents.json file back from the back up and it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally removed some assets and then returned them by means of git (just reverted deleted files from Xcode's Source Control tool) – the image files came back, but the asset didn't work and I had the same warning.

I opened the Contents.json file in the asset directory and saw that the `images` array was empty. I added my images there manually. For example:

```json
{
  "images" : [
      {
        "idiom" : "universal",
        "filename" : "Icon.png",
        "scale" : "1x"
      },
      {
        "idiom" : "universal",
        "filename" : "Icon@2x.png",
        "scale" : "2x"
      },
      {
        "idiom" : "universal",
        "filename" : "Icon@3x.png",
        "scale" : "3x"
      }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  }
}
```