# LaunchImage warning in Xcode for iOS 7 deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently changed the deployment target of my app from iOS8 to iOS7 and I am now seeing this warning in Xcode : `Applications using Launch Screen Files and targetting iOS 7.1 and earlier need to also include a Launch Image in an Asset Catalog.`

Not sure why. I have a LaunchScreen.xib setup for iOS 8 in my Images.xcassets I also have the LaunchImage with one image for each size of device for iOS 7.0 and later and also iOS 8.0 and later. Could anyone give me some pointers to why I might be seeing this warning please? Thanks!

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: iOS 7 doesn't use the launch screen file (that feature is new to iOS 8). It requires launch images.

Comment: just follow these steps; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons/22353990#22353990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general settings of your project you must select an asset catalog with the launch images for your application. See the image below.

[image: Asset catalog]

Comment: I edited my question. Mine looks a little different. I just have the "Use Asset Catalog" button then and option to migrate. Do I just hit that then Choose "Images" in the second menu?

Comment: Yes, after you have to go on "Images.xcassets" and set "Launch Image" icons