# the icon of apple watch is blank on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

[image]

I had set all watch images in AppIcon, but still could no see the icon on iPhone.
xcode 7.1
ios9.1

Comment: I don't understand the question. Which icon is missing? The one on the watch or the one on the phone?

Comment: the one on the phone.

Comment: Please follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780476/ios-7-app-icons-launch-images-and-naming-convention-while-keeping-ios-6-icons/22353990#22353990

Answer (score 0):

Your project has 3 parts:

- The Container App (running on the phone)
- The Watch App (runs on the Watch and contains the UI)
- The Watch Extension (runs in WatchKit 1 on the phone, in WatchKit 2 on the watch)

Looks like you've forgotten to add an App Icon in your container App

Comment: I had add App icon, but the icon is gone when you install the app. After you install the watch app, the icon is appear. I do know why need to install the watch app?